# Mesh XTick Labels

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the following code:

```
mesh(c_conc);
zlabel('Concentration');
title('Initial TAF Concentration');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:0.2:1)
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', 0:0.2:1)
```

Where `c_conc` is a `1000 x 1000` matrix. This produces the following result:

[image]

What I don't understand is why, given the same height and width, and the same `XTickLabel`, the x-axis is correctly set with values from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.2, whereas the y-axis only arrives to 0.4?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your data does not range further than 0.4 in the y-direction. If you want to force the plot to range to 1, use the [`ylim`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) option:

```
mesh(c_conc);
zlabel('Concentration');
ylim([0 1])
title('Initial TAF Concentration');
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', 0:0.2:1)
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', 0:0.2:1)
```